# How to create feature layer in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps-api, feature-layer, arcgis-online

In ArcGIS we have the ArcGIS Online portal kind of application where we can create a feature layer.

Is there any application where I can maintain the feature data in Google?

Or how we can do this in the Google Maps API?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "i can maintain the feature data in the google"? Where do you want to store the data? What kind of functionality do you require? Without details, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: i need to maintain user location information, where each user will enter his address. i need to maintain that in one place.. and later i need to use that data for other purpose..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps google fusion tables would be of some use to you? Basically its an online database service provided by Google, you upload your data which you can then display on a google map

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/

I hope that helps get you on your way.

Cheers